# Locally shell-process remote files?

Tags: tramp, shell-command

I'm using https://github.com/schspa/dtb-mode to transparently decompile binary dtb files; dtb-mode does this by running `dtc` on the underlying file (which, AFAICT, doesn't accept input from stdin).

While that works smoothly with local files, I'd like to also use it on an embedded target via TRAMP where `dtc` is not available. Since (as far as I can tell) `shell-command-to-string` attempts to execute commands remotely when visiting a remote file, this will obviously fail.
To work around that, I created a fork that clumsily copies remote files to a local temporary location and runs `dtc` on that (https://github.com/sebastiansturm/dtb-mode). That works, but I assume there must be a ready-made library function available somewhere that achieves the same result with less boilerplate (and more efficiently, perhaps; for example, I imagine that saving the buffer's contents to a temporary file would be faster than invoking `copy-file`).

Can anyone point me to such a library method?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info